# Comparing two and three arrays for the same values contained anyhere within the array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 3 arrays.
`$eldest_range`
`$second_range`
`$third_range`

```
$eldest_range = range($start_year1,$end_year1);
print_r($eldest_range);

$second_range = range($start_year2,$end_year2);
print_r($second_range);

$third_range = range($start_year3,$end_year3);
print_r($third_range);
```

Which returns:
`<br> Array ( [0] => 2030 [1] => 2031 [2] => 2032 [3] => 2033 [4] => 2034 [5] => 2035 ) <Br> Array ( [0] => 2032 [1] => 2033 [2] => 2034 [3] => 2035 [4] => 2036 [5] => 2037 ) <br> Array ( [0] => 2034 [1] => 2035 [2] => 2036 [3] => 2037 [4] => 2038 [5] => 2039 ) <Br>`

I want compare these arrays. To check what if any of them are present within one another. So in the above case 1 & 2 share 2032, but 1,2 & 3 share 2034.

I would rather check them separately in pairs and then as a three. (1 & 2 - 1 & 3 - 2 & 3 - 1, 2 & 3)

Here's what I have tried. This is for Eldest to second:

```
$result=array_intersect_assoc($eldest_range, $second_range);
print_r($result);
```

which returns, nothing: `array()`
and I have also tried..

```
$result=array_intersect_key($eldest_range, $second_range);
print_r($result);
```

which returns just the whole of `$eldest_range`

`Array ( [0] => 2030 [1] => 2031 [2] => 2032 [3] => 2033 [4] => 2034 [5] => 2035 )`

Am i using the wrong `array_intersect()`. I just want to see any values that are in 2 arrays. and 3 arrays (as above).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is **very useful** to read a [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php), which says that `array_intersect_assoc`

> Computes the intersection of arrays **with additional index check**

Do you need this index check? **Definitely no**.

What you need is simple `array_intersect`:

```
$eldest_range = range(2030, 2035);
$second_range = range(2032, 2037);
$third_range = range(2034, 2039);
print_r(array_intersect($eldest_range, $second_range));   // [2032, 2033, 2034, 2035]
print_r(array_intersect($eldest_range, $second_range, $third_range)); // [2034, 2035]
```

Comment: I just figured this out. Sorry to have bothered you. I did read the manual. Hence why I tried the others. I thought Key was specific. Clearly I was wrong. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: In the interest of teaching. What would the additional index be used for, for example? If you dont mind.

Comment: To check if arrays have __same value under the same key__.

Comment: So a specific to each array element?

Comment: Didn't get what you mean.

Comment: Explanation is in examples of `array_intersect_assoc`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php#refsect1-function.array-intersect-assoc-examples

Comment: Probably not the time or place. Just exploring arrays and how to deal with them. Only used them as you see above. Wondered how far down the rabbit hole you can go with them.

Comment: Just after the wisdom :)